# what i need to do to convert my current system which use cron to use RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, cron, rabbitmq, task-queue

my current script using CRON to handle the checking to DB and do the requests

so every mint the CRON will be called and check which action should be done as per the schedule table entry so if now the time to send email/publish post etc...

and this entry getting more and more with time and with many users now my CRON take around 20 to 50 mint to be done 
so if I have to send email on 10 AM it sends between 10:20 AM to 10:50 AM

after searching I found RabbitMQ and Redis and other systems and I choose RabbitMQ

so what is next, what I need to do next, as for my experience I never work with a system like Redis etc.. so its something totally new, so if someone has and resources to check read or watch and help me with migrating the whole system from CRON to RabbitMQ.

small note, the current script is built on top of custom PHP framework only for this script and don't have API.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a php shell script for create linux pid in a infinite loop and call a **method** by cron.
2. Every job push to rabbitMq basic_publish with data set.
3. this **method** create a basic_consume with rabbitMq for performing queue with queue data set.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by calling a method by CRON?